# WPF switch binding with trigger

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I'm trying to switch the ItemsSource property on a ComboBox via triggers on a checkbox. Here is my code:

```
<CheckBox Content="Test" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0">
  <CheckBox.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="CheckBox.IsChecked" Value="True">
      <Setter TargetName="MyComboBox" Property="ComboBox.ItemsSource" Value="{Binding A}" />
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="CheckBox.IsChecked" Value="False">
      <Setter TargetName="MyComboBox" Property="ComboBox.ItemsSource" Value="{Binding B}" />
    </Trigger>
  </CheckBox.Triggers>
</CheckBox>
```

As you can see, the intended purpose is to switch between binding "A" and binding "B" depending on the checkbox's IsChecked state. I've seen a lot of people put these triggers in a Style, but that gets rid of my window theme, which I want to keep. Additionally, I'd like this to be in XAML only as I need to apply this sort of binding switch to multiple combo box / checkbox pairs in my application.

The problem I'm having is that when I put in the above code my application crashes on startup! I've isolated it to the trigger code above (removing that removes the crash). Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that `MyComboBox` is not contained in the `CheckBox` and is therefore out of the naming scope that the `Trigger` is defined.

Instead of adding the trigger to the CheckBox, why not add it to the ComboBox and binding the `CheckBox.IsChecked` property to a property in your view model, like so:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding ShowComboBoxItemsA}"/>
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding A}">
    <ComboBox.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ShowAComboBoxItems}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding B}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </ComboBox.Triggers>
</ComboBox>
```

The other option would be bind the `CheckBox.IsChecked` property to a property in your view model, as in the first, but then in your setter update the value of the ComboBoxItems.

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding ShowComboBoxItemsA}"/>
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ComboBoxItems}"/> 

    public List<object> ItemsA { get; set; }
    public List<object> ItemsB { get; set; }

    bool showComboBoxItemsA;
    public bool ShowComboBoxItemsA
    {
        get { return showComboBoxItemsA; }
        set
        {
            if (showComboBoxItemsA != value)
            {
                showComboBoxItemsA = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ShowComboBoxItemsA");

                if (showComboBoxItemsA)
                    ComboBoxItems = ItemsA;
                else
                    ComboBoxItems = ItemsB;
            }
        }
    }

    List<object> comboBoxItems;
    public List<object> ComboBoxItems
    {
        get { return comboBoxItems; }
        set
        {
            comboBoxItems = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ComboBoxItems");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I found the second solution myself just after posting, I like the first solution more though because it requires less coding (one less binding to think about!). I'll have to try it.